# C user input not working (c, lua)

Tags: c, if-statement, lua

I'm trying to make a simple calc app in c and lua. But for some reason it is getting over the commands based on the input. I know the code is useless and impracticable but I'm in the process of learning to use the lua (luaJIT), c api so please bear with me. When I run this code it gets the user input (i.e add) but then does nothing and skips to the end of the code. But I put it in a infinite loop to stop this but it is still skipping the code in the if statements. Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

The C code:

```
int main()

{
fflush(stdin);
int status;
int trace = 1;
int x = 0;
lua_Number lua_tonumber (lua_State *L, int index);
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaJIT_setmode(L, trace,LUAJIT_MODE_ALLFUNC|LUAJIT_MODE_ON);
luaL_dofile(L,"fuel.lua");

while(x == 0){
printf("Enter a op (add, sub, multi, div)\n");
scanf("%s", a_word);

if(a_word == "add"){
lua_Number num1;
lua_Number num2;
printf("Enter the first number: ");
scanf("%s", num1);
printf("Enter the second number: ");
scanf("%s", num2);
lua_getglobal(L, "add");
lua_pushnumber(L, num1);
lua_pushnumber(L, num2);
lua_pcall(L,2,1,0);
int resut = lua_tonumber(L,-1);
printf("the number is %d\n", resut);
}

else if(a_word == "sub"){
lua_Number num1;
lua_Number num2;
printf("Enter the first number: ");
scanf("%d", num1);
printf("Enter the second number: ");
scanf("%d", num2);
lua_getglobal(L, "sub");
lua_pushnumber(L, num1);
lua_pushnumber(L, num2);
lua_pcall(L,2,1,0);
int resut = lua_tonumber(L,-1);
printf("the number is %d\n", resut);
}

else if(a_word == "multi"){
lua_Number num1;
lua_Number num2;
printf("Enter the first number: ");
scanf("%s", num1);
printf("Enter the second number: ");
scanf("%s", num2);
lua_getglobal(L, "mult");
lua_pushnumber(L, num1);
lua_pushnumber(L, num2);
lua_pcall(L,2,1,0);
int resut = lua_tonumber(L,-1);
printf("the number is %d\n", resut);
}

else if(a_word == "div"){
lua_Number num1;
lua_Number num2;
printf("Enter the first number: ");
scanf("%s", num1);
printf("Enter the second number: ");
scanf("%s", num2);
lua_getglobal(L, "divi");
lua_pushnumber(L, num1);
lua_pushnumber(L, num2);
lua_pcall(L,2,1,0);
int resut = lua_tonumber(L,-1);
printf("the number is %d\n", resut);
}
}
}
```

The lua file:

```
add = function(x,y)
return x+y
end

sub = function(x,y)
return x-y
end

mult = function(x,y)
return x*y
end

divi = function(x,y)
return x / y
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c you compare 'strings' using strcmp.

```
strcmp(first_char*, scnd_char*)
```

it returns 0 if they are equal, a positive or negative value if first is lexicographically bigger or smaller respectively.

More reading:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

It's for c++ but applies here aswell.

I believe what you need to do is replace:

```
if(a_word == "add")
```

With:

```
if(strcmp(a_word, "add) == 0)
```

..etc